# Socket raw em C

Tags: c

Estou querendo fazer um sniffer em C usando a API Socket.

Vi que uma boa solução era usar o socket raw:

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , 'Tipo do protocolo aqui UDP/TCP/ICMP');
```

Mas eu não entendi o fundamento do socket raw. Alguém poderia explicar como ele funciona ? Em que camadas ele atua ?

E no recvfrom :

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                 struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen)
```

Qual a real finalidade do `*buf` e do `flags` ?

E se alguém puder mostrar como pegar um campo específico de um pacote recebido com esse recvfrom eu agradeço. Pois preciso fazer um sniffer com essa API e pegar a mensagem que é transmitida por um pacote ( um número inteiro e um vetor de char transmitidas por um socker por exemplo).

Answer (score 0):

O SOCK_RAW permite tanto receber quanto enviar pacotes. A principal utilidade de SOCK_RAW é implementar novos protocolos de transporte em userspace (fora do kernel). Por exemplo, um programa que use pacotes ICMP como o ping tem de ser implementado usando esse tipo de socket.

Para fazer sniffing você estará muito mais bem servido usando libpcap, que inclusive é portável. Outra vantagem do libpcap é a eficiência: você pode filtrar por muitos parâmetros além do protocolo, e esse filtro BPF é literalmente compilado dentro do kernel para obter máxima eficiência.

Mas sim, um socket SOCK_RAW pode ser usado para "sniffar" pacotes.

O parâmetro buf é um ponteiro para um buffer (pode ser uma variável tipo char bla[4096]) com espaço suficiente para receber os pacotes.

O formato interno dos dados que você vai encontrar nesse buffer varia conforme o protocolo que você escolheu como "filtro". Por exemplo, se o protocolo for IPPROTO_RAW, você vai receber todos os pacotes IP, portanto o início do buffer conterá o cabeçalho IP, que você vai ter de parsear para descobrir o protocolo de transporte. Se usar IPPROTO_UDP, o início do buffer conterá o cabeçalho UDP, mas não o cabeçalho IP. E se usar htons(ETH_P_ALL), vai receber o pacote Ethernet inteiro, o início do buffer vai ter o cabeçalho da camada de enlace.

O parâmetro flags pode ser 0 ou pode receber um valor que modifica o comportamento da função. Há muitos deles, por exemplo o valor MSG_DONTWAIT faz a função retornar imediatamente se não há um pacote pronto para ser lido (ou seja, a função opera em modo não-bloqueante).

Esta página possui diversos exemplos de uso de SOCK_RAW: http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html

Answer (score -1):

Se você for um hacker de extremo alto nível então vocè pode pensar em criar um sniffer usando raw sockets. Caso contrário você pode fazer como a maioria das pessoas que escreve sniffers e usar uma biblioteca de captura, como a [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).